# Show Wordpress posts in more than one page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm new to Wordpress and creating a Wordpress template from scratch. I have been grinding my gears for a while and can't find a solution for the following problem.

In my front page, among with some other static content, I want to show a preview of my blog posts in a sidebar like layout. I wrote the following function in my functions.php file:

```
function show_forum_posts($preview = false) {
  if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  get_template_part($preview ? 'forum-preview-content' : 'forum-content', get_post_format());
  endwhile; endif; 
}
```

This works as expected and I can see the posts by calling this function in my index.php

The problem is that I want to have another page where I want to list all the complete blog posts.

From what I have been reading Wordpress Pages only allow static content.

After banging my head on the wall for quite a few time I created and gave all the posts a category called "Forum", and then created the category-forum.php file, in which I used the function above and successfully listed all the posts (I also tried with Pages but didn't worked out).

The problem is the link to this new page is mywebsite.com/category/forum/ and I want it to be mywebsite.com/forum/.

Although I made it work it got me thinking that this probably is not the best solution, but it was the only one I could came up with.

Any ideas on how to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) function is what you might want to use in this case.
You can pass the category parameter to your query and loop through it. You could also use 'posts_per_page' value to limit the number of posts you want to display on a page. Hope that helps.

Comment: I guess the output would be the same. My problem is where should I use it? I want to create a page to display the posts other than the index.php or a Category page.

Comment: Create a page template and assign that template to your new page. more info here https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found a great example here https://digwp.com/2013/01/display-blog-posts-on-page-with-navigation/